# How to combine several ifelse functions in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a question regarding the combination of several ifelse functions in R. When attempting to run the following line, I get a result of only "Other".

```
standardized_object_codes <- ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("GG"), "Grants",
    ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("SW"),"Salaries and Wages",
    ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("DR"), "Retirement",
    ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("DO"), "Nonretirement",
    ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("PC"), "Contracts", "Other")))))
```

This is definitely not normal as my data contains all of the object codes that are listed in the function above (GG, SW, DR, DO and PC). Could you please help me out with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: One way to achieve this is by a lookup table and then `merge` it back.

Comment: (this is not the only duplicate, just the first one I found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow-up to my comment above, you could try

```
standardized_object_codes <- with(Spending_1, dplyr::case_when(
    OBJECT_CODE == "GG" ~ "Grant",
    OBJECT_CODE == "SW" ~ "Salaries and Wages",
    OBJECT_CODE == "DR" ~ "Retirement",
    OBJECT_CODE == "DO" ~ "Nonretirement",
    OBJECT_CODE == "PC" ~ "Contracts",
    TRUE ~ "Other"))
```

Or create a lookup table and use `match` to match entries.

```
df.lookup <- data.frame(
    OBJECT_CODE = c("GG", "SW", "DR", "DO", "PC"),
    Description = c("Grant", "Salaries and Wages", "Retirement", "Nonretirement", "Contracts"),
    stringsAsFactors = F)

standardized_object_codes <- replace(
    x <- df.lookup$Description[match(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE, df.lookup$OBJECT_CODE)], 
    is.na(x), "Other")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use factor labels:

```
lev = c("GG", "SW", "DR", "DO", "PC","others")
lab = c("Grant", "Salaries and Wages", "Retirement", "Nonretirement", "Contracts","others")

#Now change everything not in lev to "others"
newf = ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% lev, Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE, "others")

as.character(factor(newf, lev, lab)) #change all names at once
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work when provided a vector in a data frame.

```
> Spending_1 <- data.frame(OBJECT_CODE = c("GG", "SW", "DR", "DO", "PC", "Other"))
> standardized_object_codes <- ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("GG"), "Grants",
                               ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("SW"),"Salaries and Wages",
                               ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("DR"), "Retirement",
                               ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("DO"), "Nonretirement",
                               ifelse(Spending_1$OBJECT_CODE %in% c("PC"), "Contracts", "Other")))))

> standardized_object_codes
[1] "Grants"             "Salaries and Wages" "Retirement"        
[4] "Nonretirement"      "Contracts"          "Other"
```

If you're not getting the result you want, it may have to do with the way your data is structured, or how you are applying your code.